# Dynamic Time Warp through SPTK tool

Tags: audio, speech-processing, cepstral-analysis

I'm an IT student and got an assignment to do about Dynamic Time Warping(DTW) using the Speech Signal Processing Toolkit (SPTK) and comparing some words spoken by 2 speakers and finding the similarities. I managed to get the SPTK working, collected 8 people(4 females, 4 males) who recorded 8 words each for me(same words for every person) and saved them as files with a *.wav* extension.

My *.wav* files are in the following format:

- RIFF (little-endian) data ;
- WAVE audio ;
- mono ;
- sampled at $16\text{ kHz}$.

I transfered every *.wav* file into *.raw* data files with the **SPTK** conversion function :

```
wav2raw +f source_maleA.wav
```

The *.raw* file I get is:

- Unsigned 8 bit ;
- Sampled at $8 \text{ kHz}$ ;
- Mono.

I transfered every *.raw* file to a *.mcep* file with this line of code:

```
x2x +Sf < source_maleA.raw | frame -l 320 -p 160 -n | window -l 320 -L 512 -n 1 | mcep -l 512 -m 13 -a 0.42 > source_maleA.mcep
```

After that, I went to compare the *.mcep* files with this line of code:

```
dtw -m 13 -s Scorefile target_maleB.mcep < source_maleA.mcep > source_maleA_target_maleB.dtw
```

The output of that command line (the "Scorefile") is a binary file.

I programmed a code that decodes the binary sequence written inside of the Scorefile and the output is some kind of decimal number: $0.678382$, which could imply a percentage of something.

Since by the **SPTK** documentation they are using some *.short* files of their own, I tried to remove the header of the *.wav* files and use them as *.raw* format and then convert it to *.mcep* file for the further use.

Since my understanding of DTW is limited by itself, plus my understanding of the *SPTK* tool is also limited, could anyone tell me if what I did is good?

I divided the files into frames of $320$ samples and periods of 160 and I used $x[0]$ as the first point of the first frame. I applied a Blackman's window of **512** samples length with the normalization computed by this function:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{L-1} w^2 (n) = 1 $$

After that I used the **mel cepstral analysis** to get the coefficients with $alpha = 0.42$ and I set the mc order to $13$.

Since when changing the length of the window, frames, period etc. etc. I don't get any better result, could anyone explain me what would be a good setup for all those factors?

[Link to the SPTK (for the documentation and examples)](http://sp-tk.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: you say "I programmed a code that decodes the binary sequence written inside of the Scorefile". What decoding did you use? Just natural binary decoding? Also I didn't quite get the cepstral analysis part. Where does it come, after or before the DTW?

Comment: Natural binary decoding yeah. I actually applied the cepstral analysis through the mcep command. It comes before the dtw.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation clearly says (emphasis mine):

> If **–s** option is specified, the score calculated by
>   dynamic time warping, that is, ***the distance between the test data and the reference data is output and sent to Scorefile***.

That means that your decimal number, $0.678382$, is the actual DTW distance between your 2 speech samples.

Now DTW is a distance measurement, and as any distance it only gives you relative information. For example, you could set a treshold and says that under this treshold, the 2 signals correspond to the same word.  If you apply DTW on a pitch contour, you could determine whether the 2 melodies are similar (that's used in query by humming).

Of course, the physical meaning of the distance depends completely on the one of the time series compared : if you compare voltage values, or frequency values, etc.
In your case, you compare normalized volumes mapped to unsigned 8-bit data.

I advise you to learn [more about DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) and to try to analyse what the distance actually tells you, and how that relates to your application

Comment: The thing is that when I compare 2 files that are kind of related(like same word or same speaker) the result is 0.678382 and in some cases when i compare two different speakers saying different stuff(with different accents) the result is not that different and since with most of the stuff in the documentation I had a hard time to get by(some were working fine, some were not and some were not working at all) I was wondering what the results were. I expected some numbers as results, but not so small.